# How can I setup a development environment based on ant and ivy that embedds and starts jetty on a task?

Tags: java, ant, jakarta-ee, ivy

I don't use eclipse and would like to setup an ant/ivy build script for web app development. The build script can only assume that the jdk/ant are installed on the system, the rest must be downloaded automatically.

Everything must be done trough ant targets/tasks, so I would probably have a 'debug' target tha would start jetty in embedded mode and configure it to use my build directory as the web app root.

How can I setup ant/ivy to automatically download a jetty webserver, and start debugging my web app with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use IVY you need an ivy lib. You could download it with the [`<get />`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) task, but then you could just use `<get />` for the jetty libs as well.
2. Download the libs for jetty and put them into a local folder (use ivys [inline-retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) or the get-task)
3. Use the [`<java />`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) Task to run/configure the Jetty-Server. Use `<jvmargs>` attribute to set Debugging. or use the [jetty-ant-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Ant+Jetty+Plugin)